# Не могу cмонтировать скрытый раздел Veracrypt

Tags: linux, криптография

При попытки смонтировать в терминале скрытый раздел выдает ошибку:

```
Error: device-mapper: reload ioctl on veracrypt1 failed: Invalid argument
Command failed
```

Ввожу такие команды

```
veracrypt --mount
Enter volume path: /dev/sda6
Enter mount directory [default]: /mnt/vera
Enter password for /dev/sda6: 
Enter PIM for /dev/sda6: 159
Enter keyfile [none]: 
Protect hidden volume (if any)? (y=Yes/n=No) [No]: n
```